# convert string of int to array of int

Tags: d

Suppose I need to read a line from a file, containing an unknown number of space separated ints.
How can I read a line and convert it into an array of ints?

What is one simple way of solving this problem in D?

My current non working attempt.

```
auto f = File("in");
foreach(line; f.byLine()){
  int[] arr;
  foreach(num; line.split())
    arr[] = cast(int)num;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using splitter, map and array:

```
import std.algorithm : map, splitter;
import std.stdio : File;
import std.conv : to;
import std.array : array;

void main(string[] args)
{
    // range result
    auto result = File("in")
        .byLine
        .map!((line) => splitter(line).map!((a) => to!int(a)));

    // multidimensioanl array result
    int[][] resultArr = File("in")
        .byLine
        .map!((line) => splitter(line).map!((a) => to!int(a)).array).array;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `map`:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.algorithm;
import std.conv : to; 
void main()
{
    auto f = File("in");
    foreach(line; f.byLine()){
        auto arr = map!(to!int)(splitter(line));
        writeln(arr);
    }   
}
```

Comment: I would point out that that solution does not result in an array of ints. It _does_ result in a range of ints, but you're going to have to use std.array.array to convert the range returned by map into an array in order to get an array.